# IPHONE - Plotting location in UIView with XY coordinates iphone SDK

Tags: iphone

Here is my question , I want to create a soccer match team formation for an app base on the X and Y coordinates return.
Does anyone have the example or tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a really good framework for plotting called [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/). I tried that before, it's a great framework you can draw plot like you deal with TableView. If you serious about plotting the you should have a look at it. If not then it maybe a bit over-kill.